# python : How to acces a element in a dict which ias also inside another dict

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

example dict

```
newlist={1:{1: {'_name': 'michael', 'id': '001', 'rating': '10', 'role': 'general_manager'},
        2: {'_name': 'mohamad', 'id': '002', 'rating': '9.5', 'role': 'team_leader'},
        3: {'_name': 'johnny', 'id': '003', 'rating': '9', 'role': 'developer'},
        4: {'_name': 'nicholos', 'id': '004', 'rating': '9', 'role': 'tech_support'}},
    2: {1: {'_name': 'michael', 'id': '001', 'rating': '10', 'role': 'general_manager'},
        2: {'_name': 'mohamad', 'id': '002', 'rating': '9.5', 'role': 'team_leader'},
        3: {'_name': 'johnny', 'id': '003', 'rating': '9', 'role': 'developer'},
        5: {'_name': 'nawaz', 'id': '005', 'rating': '8.5', 'role': 'intern'}},
    3: {1: {'_name': 'michael', 'id': '001', 'rating': '10', 'role': 'general_manager'},
        2: {'_name': 'mohamad', 'id': '002', 'rating': '9.5', 'role': 'team_leader'},
        4: {'_name': 'rogers', 'id': '004', 'rating': '9', 'role': 'tech_support'},
        5: {'_name': 'nawaz', 'id': '005', 'rating': '8.5', 'role': 'intern'}},
    4: {1: {'_name': 'michael', 'id': '001', 'rating': '10', 'role': 'general_manager'},
        3: {'_name': 'johnny', 'id': '003', 'rating': '9', 'role': 'developer'},
        4: {'_name': 'gargano', 'id': '004', 'rating': '9', 'role': 'tech_support'},
        5: {'_name': 'nawaz', 'id': '005', 'rating': '8.5', 'role': 'intern'}},
    5: {2: {'_name': 'mohamad', 'id': '002', 'rating': '9.5', 'role': 'team_leader'},
        3: {'_name': 'johnny', 'id': '003', 'rating': '9', 'role': 'developer'},
        4: {'_name': 'williams', 'id': '004', 'rating': '9', 'role': 'tech_support'},
        5: {'_name': 'nawaz', 'id': '005', 'rating': '8.5', 'role': 'intern'}}}

for k in range(len(new_list)):
    for l in k:
        m = new_list[k][role]['tech_support']
```

i want to get all  'tech_support' roles from list. how can i access key values inside a dict which i aslo inside another dict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
# user parameters 
role = 'role'
key = 'tech_support'

# method One
result = []
for i in newlist:
    for j in newlist[i]:
        if newlist[i][j][role] is key:
            result.append(newlist[i][j])

# method two
output = [newlist[i][j] for i in newlist for j in newlist[i] if newlist[i][j][role] is  key]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below code and see if you are getting desired output?

```
for key, val in newlist.items():
    for k1, v1 in val.items():
        if v1['role'] == 'tech_support':
            print(v1)
```

Comment: yes. it's working..Thank you...@nalanagula....so its possible for any number of dicts inside another if we use key and values both as variable..right??

Comment: you can have any number of (key:dict) in sub dictionary and it works

Answer (score 0):

this is really messed up. you should try another method. but if you insist try this code:

```
new_list={1:{1: {'_name': 'michael', 'id': '001', 'rating': '10', 'role': 'general_manager'},
        2: {'_name': 'mohamad', 'id': '002', 'rating': '9.5', 'role': 'team_leader'},
        3: {'_name': 'johnny', 'id': '003', 'rating': '9', 'role': 'developer'},
        4: {'_name': 'nicholos', 'id': '004', 'rating': '9', 'role': 'tech_support'}},
    2: {1: {'_name': 'michael', 'id': '001', 'rating': '10', 'role': 'general_manager'},
        2: {'_name': 'mohamad', 'id': '002', 'rating': '9.5', 'role': 'team_leader'},
        3: {'_name': 'johnny', 'id': '003', 'rating': '9', 'role': 'developer'},
        5: {'_name': 'nawaz', 'id': '005', 'rating': '8.5', 'role': 'intern'}},
    3: {1: {'_name': 'michael', 'id': '001', 'rating': '10', 'role': 'general_manager'},
        2: {'_name': 'mohamad', 'id': '002', 'rating': '9.5', 'role': 'team_leader'},
        4: {'_name': 'rogers', 'id': '004', 'rating': '9', 'role': 'tech_support'},
        5: {'_name': 'nawaz', 'id': '005', 'rating': '8.5', 'role': 'intern'}},
    4: {1: {'_name': 'michael', 'id': '001', 'rating': '10', 'role': 'general_manager'},
        3: {'_name': 'johnny', 'id': '003', 'rating': '9', 'role': 'developer'},
        4: {'_name': 'gargano', 'id': '004', 'rating': '9', 'role': 'tech_support'},
        5: {'_name': 'nawaz', 'id': '005', 'rating': '8.5', 'role': 'intern'}},
    5: {2: {'_name': 'mohamad', 'id': '002', 'rating': '9.5', 'role': 'team_leader'},
        3: {'_name': 'johnny', 'id': '003', 'rating': '9', 'role': 'developer'},
        4: {'_name': 'williams', 'id': '004', 'rating': '9', 'role': 'tech_support'},
        5: {'_name': 'nawaz', 'id': '005', 'rating': '8.5', 'role': 'intern'}}}

for k in new_list.values():
    for l in k.values():
        for m in l.values():
            if 'tech_support' in m:
                print(l)
```

Comment: your code givng me the same output twice which i requied....the above 1 worked fine

Comment: you sure? this code gives you four outputs, all characteristics are the same but different _name. check again

Comment: yes its working.... i rechecked it..thanks a lot....will u suggest me a best reference for dicct @Shoaib Mirzaei

Comment: dict is just a type of data in python. I think python documentation or w3schools or even pythonprogramming.net are good to go. but you are a java programmer what do you need python for?